# Ember JS and nested routes: the provided route name is invalid

Tags: ember.js

I'm currently working my way through my first Ember JS app, using Balint Erdi's excellent book "Rock and Roll with Ember JS"

I'm stumped and would appreciate some help.

I have the following (fairly simple) routes for my app:

```
/clients  
/clients/:slug  
/clients/:slug/requests
```

So for example, I would want a user to be able to view the requests for a specific client by visiting `/clients/abc-company/requests`

On the main dashboard, inside `clients.hbs`, I have the following code to link to each specific client (using dynamic segments):

```
  {{#each model as |item|}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{item.id}}</td>
    <td>{{#link-to "clients.client.requests" client}}
      {{item.name}}
    {{/link-to}}</td>
    <td>{{item.contact}}</td>
    <td>{{item.email}}</td>
    <td>{{item.phone}}</td>
  </tr>
  {{/each}}
```

Now, the issue is that Ember doesn't seem to recognize the second link-to parameter (`client`).

The console is yelling at me with the following error message:

```
WARNING: This link-to is in an inactive loading state because at least one 
of its parameters presently has a null/undefined value, or the provided 
route name is invalid.
```

but I DID pass the parameters, which is supposed to be `client`!

Here are the relevant files in my code, I'm hoping someone can point out my obvious mistake or find the semi-colon that I forgot to include, or something.

```
//app/router.js
(...)
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('clients', function() {
    this.route('client', { path: ':slug' }, function() {
      this.route('requests');
    });
  });
});

//app/routes/clients.js
(...)
var Client = EmberObject.extend({
  id: '',
  name: '',
  contact: '',
  email: '',
  phone: '',
// create slug from client name
  slug: computed('name', function() {
    return this.get('name').dasherize();
  })
});

// app/routes/clients/client.js <-- see the route DOES exist
(...)
  model: function(params) {
    // get the slug from clients, return client matching the slug name in the URL
    var clients = this.modelFor('clients');
    return clients.findBy('slug', params.slug);
  }
});

// app/routes/clients/client/requests.js
(...)
  model: function() {
    return this.modelFor('clients.client');
  }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated, this is my first Ember.js hurdle and I have a feeling that understanding nested routes properly will be very useful in the future :)

But for now I'm just confused.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: Added some more code from the template, for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annnnd I figured it out.

Lesson 1: When Ember complains that the model you want is invalid and you *think* you created the route, make sure you actually import the route at the top of the route file (`import Route from '@ember/routing/route';`)

Mine was missing for some reason and I didn't see it

Lesson 2: In the template file, the parameter needed by #link-to isn't actually the name of the route/model. It's the name of whatever you choose to call your iteration in the each loop.

This is wrong:

```
{{#each model as |item|}}
<tr>
<td>{{item.id}}</td>
<td>{{#link-to "clients.client.requests" client}}
{{/each}}
```

This is correct:

```
{{#each model as |client|}}
<tr>
<td>{{client.id}}</td>
<td>{{#link-to "clients.client.requests" client}}
```

I have no idea if this information will ever help anyone. In any case, I shall proceed to self high-five myself.

**EDIT**: Looks like i have to wait 2 days before I can accept my own answer.

Cheers!